# How to temporarily disable conditionally rendered buttons in Vue JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have 2 groups of conditionally rendered buttons.

When a campaign is running
[image]

When a campaign isn't running 
[image]

What I want to do is disable the play button after the campaign has been paused for 5 seconds.

This is my markup:

```
<div class='m1 '>

  <md-button v-on:click='changeCampaignStatus(campaign.id, "Paused")' v-if='campaign.state==="Running"' class='md-icon-button md-accent md-raised' id='run-button'>
    <md-icon>pause</md-icon>
  </md-button>

  <md-button v-on:click='changeCampaignStatus(campaign.id, "Running")' v-if='campaign.state==="Paused"' class='md-icon-button md-accent md-raised' id='run-button'>
    <md-icon>play_arrow</md-icon>
  </md-button>

  <md-button v-on:click='changeCampaignStatus(campaign.id, "Canceled")' v-if='campaign.state==="Paused"' class='md-icon-button md-accent md-raised' id='run-button'>
    <md-icon>stop</md-icon>
  </md-button>

  <md-button v-on:click='deleteCampaign(campaign.id)' v-if='campaign.state==="Canceled"' class='md-icon-button md-accent md-raised' id='run-button'>
    <md-icon>delete_forever</md-icon>
  </md-button>

  <md-button v-on:click='duplicateCampaign(campaign.id)' class='md-icon-button md-accent md-raised'>
    <md-icon>content_copy</md-icon>
  </md-button>

  <md-button v-on:click='goToEdit'  v-if='campaign.state==="Paused"' class='md-icon-button md-accent md-raised'>
    <md-icon>mode_edit</md-icon>
  </md-button>
  <div>
    <md-chip v-for='tag in campaign.tags' :key='tag' class='mr1'>{{tag}}</md-chip>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm not exactly sure which buttons should have the `id='run-button'`, I believe the conditional rendering is making the following setTimeout behave strangely:

```
  document.getElementById("run-button").disabled = false;
  setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("run-button").disabled = true;},5000);
```

With this logic I can get the button to be initially enabled and be disabled after 5 seconds, but if I switch the booleans (first line `true`, second line `false`) it somehow just messes up everything. Why is this happening?

How can I implement this correctly?

Comment: You should not combine vanilla javascript together with vue, this can cause vue to revert certain modifications on the elements when you don't want this, or not notice those changes, and re-use the element somewhere else

Comment: ID elements should be unique. The problem is that you have many elements with same id. If you change for just the button you will actually stop, it will probably work.

Comment: @Ferrybig does Vue 2 actually have an equivalent to this vanilla JS solution? I see they deprecated such functionalities in v2

Comment: Inside your data, add `playEnabled: false`, and inside your timeout do `this.playEnabled = true` inside an *array function*, then inside your view do `:disabled=playEnabled`, this doesn't fix your original problem however

Comment: @VictorOliveira actually, what I was doing before this was adding the id solely to the play button. The result is getting a `Cannot set property 'disabled' of null`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't mix Vue and direct DOM manipulation.

Optimal solution here is to create a property that will tell if it has been pause by more than 5 seconds, and add such property to `:disabled`.

For instance,

```
data() {
  return {
    // ...
    pausedFor5Seconds: false,
    // ...
  };
},
// ...
methods: {
  // ...
  pause() {
    // some mutation that sets campaign.state to "Paused"
    this.pausedFor5Seconds = false;
    setTimeout(() => this.pausedFor5Seconds = true, 5000);
  },
  play() {
    // some mutation that sets campaign.state to "Running"
    this.pausedFor5Seconds = false;
  }
}
```

Being `pause` and `play`, as the comments say, the methods where you mutate the `campaign.state`.

And in your template add `:disabled="pausedFor5Seconds"`:

```
<md-button v-on:click='changeCampaignStatus(campaign.id, "Running")'
  v-if='campaign.state==="Paused"' class='md-icon-button md-accent md-raised'
  :disabled="pausedFor5Seconds">
    <md-icon>play_arrow</md-icon>
</md-button>
```

And the `id` is not even necessary anymore (which, by the way, you have multiple elements with the same `run-button` id -- that's invalid HTML and messes up your `document.getElementById()`s).

Comment: Thank you so much @acdcjunior ! Just a little change though. There's a `changeCampaignStatus`function which is the mutation that sets `campaign.state`to a given state that enters as a parameter. Adding ```      vc.pausedFor5Seconds = true;
      setTimeout(() => this.pausedFor5Seconds = false, 5000);```(notice the reversed boolean logic) there will solve the problem.

Comment: Oh, I see, yes, makes sense.